# Symfony2 / KitpagesDataGridBundle entities manipulation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am using Symfony 2.7 and [KitpagesDataGridBundle](https://github.com/kitpages/KitpagesDataGridBundle)

I am developing an application for a school in which I have two entities with a 1-N relationship: Section-Courses.

Here are the two entities:

**Section**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="my\SiteBundle\Entity\Course", mappedBy="section", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $courses;
```

**Course**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="my\SiteBundle\Entity\Section", inversedBy="courses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $section;
```

Now, I'd like to be able to retrieve the linked 'course' objects from the section and iterate over them in the Twig template. For the time being, as I haven't been able to do so, I've created a prototype which will concatenate the courses names and IDs as string in Section's repository using the query builder, and then parse those concatenations in the Twig template as such:

**SectionRepository**

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder
 */
public function getGridQueryBuilder()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb
        ->select('s, GroupConcat(c.name SEPARATOR \'|\') as courses, GroupConcat(c.id SEPARATOR \'|\') as coursesID')
        ->leftJoin('s.courses', 'c')
        ->groupBy('s.id')
        ->orderBy('s.name');

    return $qb;
}
```

**SectionController**

(The 'Dummy[CoursesNames]' field allows me to perform a search on the courses names)

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $qb = $this->getRepository('mySiteBundle:Section')->getGridQueryBuilder();

    // Grid config
    $gridConfig = new GridConfig();
    $gridConfig
        ->setName('sectionsList')
        ->setQueryBuilder($qb)
        ->setCountFieldName('s.id')
        ->addField(new Field('s.name',['label'=>'Section name', 'filterable'=>true]))
        ->addField(new Field('c.name', ['label'=>'Dummy[CoursesNames]', 'filterable'=>true, 'visible'=>false]));

    // Paginator config
    $this->setGridPaginator($gridConfig, 5);

    return $this->render('mySiteBundle:Section:index.html.twig', ['grid' => $this->getGrid($gridConfig, $request)]);
}
```

**Section Twig template**

What I currently have:

```
{% embed kitpages_data_grid.grid.default_twig with {'grid': grid} %}

{% block kit_grid_thead_column %}
    <th>Courses list</th>
{% endblock %}

{% block kit_grid_tbody_column %}
    {% set courses = item['courses']|split('|') %}
    {% set coursesID = item['coursesID']|split('|') %}

    <!-- Courses -->
    <td>
        {% for course in courses %}
            {% if not course is empty %}
                <a href="{{ path ("viewCourse", {"id": coursesID[loop.index0] }) }}" ><span class="label label-primary">{{ course }}</span></a>
            {% else %}
                (No results)
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </td>

{% endblock %}

{% endembed %}
```

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
{% embed kitpages_data_grid.grid.default_twig with {'grid': grid} %}

{% block kit_grid_thead_column %}
    <th>Courses list</th>
{% endblock %}

{% block kit_grid_tbody_column %}

    <!-- Courses -->
    <td>

        {# here using section object #}

        {% for course in section.courses %}
            <a href="{{ path ("viewCourse", {"id": course.id }) }}" ><span class="label label-primary">{{ course.name }}</span></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </td>

{% endblock %}

{% endembed %}
```

Even though my prototype works well, I do not like the parsing stuff at all, and would by far prefer working with the section objects.

I've tried to do something like

```
{{ item['s'].name }}
```

in the template but I received this error message:
*Key "s" for array with keys "s.id, s.name, courses, coursesID" does not exist* , although I did a "select('s')" in the query builder.

I don't know if what I'd like to do is possible. Otherwise, I am considering dropping the KitPages stuff and build my tables myself in the templates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that what I wanted is not possible as I believe that, as KitPages DataGrid is using the querybuilder, I would not be able to retrieve entities without having to change the bundle logic. I therefore reverted to entities sent to Twig, and iterated over their attributes in a table.